# django intcomma not working with localization

Tags: django

I'm using django and I realized that `intcomma` template tag not working in special languages!

When the `locale` is `en` it works fine, but when I want to use persian language (locale `fa`) nothing really happens and django doesn't humanize the number

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The tag does not know how to format numbers for the Persian language and leaves them unchanged. Try to use tag like this

```
{{ value|intcomma:False }}
```

The first argument of `intcomma` is `use_l10n`. Passing `False` to it force tag to use default behavior.

Comment: This saved me after hours of struggling! Thank you. BTW, is it possible to submit a PR to django repository to change this? As far as I know (as a native), comma separation works the same in Persian as in English.